# Seemingly missing file when using JanRain OpenID PHP library with MySQL

Tags: php, openid, janrain

I've just set up the JanRain OpenID library for PHP (https://github.com/openid/php-openid).  I'm attempting to use the example server file, and the error I get is:

> Warning: require_once(DB.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/file/examples/server/config.php on line 28

I have searched the package and have not found any such file (DB.php).  I do not see mention of it being generated.  The config file I'm using was generated by the JanRain library's setup.php script.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what this file (which the library seems to expect) is and how I can obtain it?

Answer (score 0):

DB.php is a part of pear DB package,

```
#pear install DB
```

for centos 6.x

```
#pear install DB-1.8.2
```

Thank for http://nobuneko.com/blog/archives/2016/01/php_533_pear_install_db_failed_php_540_higher.html